# clearInterval not working | undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such jQuery code and have problem with clearing intervals.

```
    var secs = 50, width = 100; 
    var counter = function() {
    if(secs > 0) {
        secs--;
        width = width - 2;
        $('#time').css('width', width + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', width);
        $('.seconds').html(secs);
    } else if(secs == 0){
        $('.questions').addClass('hidden');
        $('.results').removeClass('hidden');
        clearInterval(counter);
        setInterval(winner, 3000);
    }
};
var winner = function() {   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {
            func: "game_results"
        },

        error: function() {
            swal("Błąd", "Serwer nie odpowiada, spróbuj ponownie", "error")
        },
        success: function(data) {

            if (data == "you") {
                $('.waiting').addClass('hidden');
                $('.you').removeClass('hidden');                    
            } else if (data == "opponent") {
                $('.waiting').addClass('hidden');
                $('.opponent').removeClass('hidden');               
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(clearInterval(winner)); // heer
}

function answer(question_id, answer, question) {
    var question_higher = question_id + 1;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {
            func: "play",
            answer: answer,
            question: question
        },

        error: function() {
            swal("Błąd", "Serwer nie odpowiada, spróbuj ponownie", "error")
        },
        success: function(data) {

            if (data == "wrong") {
                $.playSound('build/sounds/wrong');
                $('*[data-question="' + question_id + '"]').find('.' + answer + '').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-danger');
                $('*[data-question="' + question_id + '"]').find('.col-sm-12').addClass('dimmed');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('*[data-question="' + question_id + '"]').addClass('hidden');
                    $('*[data-question="' + question_higher + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
                }, 750);
            } else if (data == "correct") {
                $.playSound('build/sounds/correct');
                $('*[data-question="' + question_id + '"]').find('.' + answer + '').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');
                $('*[data-question="' + question_id + '"]').find('.col-sm-12').addClass('dimmed');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('*[data-question="' + question_id + '"]').addClass('hidden');
                    $('*[data-question="' + question_higher + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
                }, 750);
            }
        }
    });

    if(question_id == 5) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        setTimeout(function() {
        //$('.questions').addClass('hidden');
        $('.results').removeClass('hidden');
        }, 750);
        setInterval(winner, 3000);      
    }

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*[data-question="1"]').removeClass('hidden');
    setInterval(counter, 1000);
});
```

Im trying to get this work for almost 5 hours without results.
Both `clearInterval(counter);` and `clearInterval(winner)` are not working and flooding my server with requets.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Include all relevant code in OP. read on [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The interval Id which is returned by `setInterval` should be passed to `clearInterval`. Example: `var interval = serInterval(myFun, 1000);`, then to clear interval `clearInterval(interval);`

Comment: it is passed but not working like it should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see how you're clearing the interval.

```
clearInterval(winner)
```

where, `winner` is the function. To clear the interval, the ID of the interval should be passed as parameter.

When setting the interval, catch the interval ID in a variable

```
winnerInterval = setInterval(winner, 3000);
```

and use this variable to clear interval.

```
clearInterval(winnerInterval);
```

Make sure the variable containing interval ID is in the scope when clearing the interval.

See [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval).